# Multiselect not working inside ui:repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, bootstrap-multiselect

I am trying to implement multi-select box for each entry inside ui:repeat. 
I tried initializing it on document.ready and inside ui:repeat. It is being applied to the top first row only.

```
    <ui:repeat id="repeat" value="#{bean.list}" var="item" varStatus="status"><h:form id="supervisorCircleForm">
                                                                    <p:dataTable id="supervisor_table" var="pass"
                                                                                 value="#{bean.insideList}">
                                                                        <p:column headerText="Name" styleClass="center">
                                                                            <h:outputText value="#{pass.memberName}"/>
                                                                        </p:column>
                                                                        <p:column headerText="Companies"
                                                                                  styleClass="center">
                                                                            <select id="taxiCircle" multiple="multiple">
                                                                                <c:forEach var="item"
                                                                                           items="${bean.companyList}">
                                                                                    <option value="${item.value}">${item.label}</option>
                                                                                </c:forEach>
                                                                            </select>
<script type="text/javascript">
                                                                                            (function(){
                                                                                                $('#taxiCircle').multiselect();
                                                                                                console.log("Func Called");
                                                                                            })();
                                                                                        </script>                                                                        </p:column>
                                                                    </p:dataTable>
                                                                </h:form>
</ui:repeat>
```

The initialise part is being called every time but the select box appears only once. I tried calling it in document.ready too. 
[image: Multiselect coming only once]

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: There are no errors.

Comment: remove the script tag from the loop , change your UNIQUE id to a class

Comment: Yes, it worked. But why is it showing both select and multiselect.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove your `script` tag from `ui:repeat` as it is not required to be repeated and move it after closing `body`.
2. You need to use unique `id` for your elements always. If not then change it `class` instead.

   ```
       <ui:repeat id="repeat" value="#{bean.list}" var="item" varStatus="status"><h:form id="supervisorCircleForm">
            <p:dataTable id="supervisor_table" var="pass" value="#{bean.insideList}">
                <p:column headerText="Name" styleClass="center">
                   <h:outputText value="#{pass.memberName}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Companies" styleClass="center">
                   <select class="taxiCircle" multiple="multiple">
                      <c:forEach var="item" items="${bean.companyList}">
                          <option value="${item.value}">${item.label}  </option>                 
                      </c:forEach>
                   </select>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
         </h:form>
       </ui:repeat>
       <script type="text/javascript">
           (function(){
             $('.taxiCircle').multiselect();
              console.log("Func Called");
             })();
       </script>
   ```